# Autofac is not creating complex objects successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I am new to Autofac based dependency injection. As per our company requirements, I have to use it in the new web API I am creating. The following is my code. I am using IocConfig class for Autofac to create and inject objects in my Web API.

```
public class MemberCodeController : ApiController
{
    private IMemberStrategy memberStrategy;
    private IMemberDetail memberDetail;

    //Constructor dependency injection through Autofac
    public MemberCodeController(IMemberStrategy memberStrategy, 
              IMemberDetail memberDetail)
    {
        this.memberStrategy = memberStrategy;
    }

public IHttpActionResult CreateMember(string email)
    {
         memberDetail.DataFields.RegisterCode  = GetCode();
         memberDetail.Email = email;
    }
}

The MemberDetail class:

public interface IMemberDetail
{
  String Email { get; set; }
  DataFields DataFields { get; set; }
}

public class MemberDetail : IMemberDetail
{     
  public String Email { get; set; }
  public DataFields DataFields { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataFields
{
  String RegisterCode { get; set; }
}
public class DataFields : IDataFields
{
  public String RegisterCode { get; set; }
}
```

IocConfig:

```
public class IocConfig
{
    //Autofac configuration
    public static void Configure()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());           
        builder.RegisterType<MemberStrategy>().As<IMemberStrategy>();
        builder.RegisterType<DataFields>().As<IDataFields>();
        builder.RegisterType<MemberDetail>().As<IMemberDetail>();
        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver resolver = new 
        AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I try to use this line,
    memberDetail.DataFields.RegisterCode  = GetCode();
The DataFields is null. Obviously, Autofac is not creating it while it constructs the MemberDetail object.

Comment: There is the PropertiesAutowired property, however, that may not do what you think. It is more common to inject via constructors vs properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemberDetail does not show a dependency on IDataFields in its constructor.

So Autofac does not create an instance for that dependency.

Adding a dependency like this would inject an instance:

```
public class MemberDetail : IMemberDetail
{     
  public String Email { get; set; }
  public IDataFields DataFields { get; set; }

  public MemberDetail(IDataFields dataFields)
  {
    DataFields = dataFields;
  }
}
```

I also changed the DataFields member type to IDataFields to make the dependency on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

MemberDetail object has been created properly. What you are missing is initialization of DataFields property. Add constructor to the DataFields class and initialize DataFields property there and you problem will go away.